# Delete all files & directories in a folder except one file

Tags: linux, command, rm

I want to delete all files & directories in a folder say 'A'. But except one file in that folder say .keep. I have tried the following command.

```
find A ! -name '.keep' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

But above command also deletes folder A. I do not want that. There are several answers related to this. But they all mentions going into that directory. I want to mention that directory in the command without cd-eing into the directory.

Comment: `find A -mindepth 1 ! -name '.keep' -delete`

Comment: @ymonad will that work recursively?

Comment: It depends on what recursive means. it deletes `A/hoo` `A/B/hoo` `A/A/ (if empty)` , does not delete  `A`, `A/.keep` `A/B/.keep`. If it is not you want, you should write what you want to delete and what you want to preserve more precisely.

Comment: By the way, your command should not delete folder A because you specified `-type f`. Does your command really deletes it ?

Comment: @ymonad. your command worked

Answer (score 0):

We can use the find command to filter the content and pass the output to the xargs to remove.

you can use the below example as reference.

Example: 
I have folders folder{1..15} in a folder called test. and using find and xargs I will delete all folders except folder 6 and 11.

1. listing folders 
   ~/Desktop/MyDocuments/scripts/test$ ls 
   folder1  folder10  folder11  folder12  folder13  folder14  folder15  folder2  folder3  folder4  folder5  folder6  folder7  folder8  folder9
2. Using find command to filter.
   ~/Desktop/MyDocuments/scripts/test$ **find . ( ! -name folder6 -and ! -iname folder11 -and ! -iname "." )**
   ./folder1
   ./folder2
   ./folder3
   ./folder4
   ./folder5
   ./folder7
   ./folder8
   ./folder9
   ./folder10
   ./folder12
   ./folder13
   ./folder14
   ./folder15
3. remove the folders with xargs.
   ~/Desktop/MyDocuments/scripts/test$ find . ( ! -name folder6 -and ! -iname folder11 -and ! -iname "." ) | **xargs -I {} rm -rf {}**
4. All folders removed except folder 6 and 11.
   ~/Desktop/MyDocuments/scripts/test$ ls 
   folder11  folder6